# trouble installing java 8

Tags: java, jdk

I am trying to install java 8 on my Ubuntu 18.0.4 system. I currently have java 1.7. I tried running: sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk. It worked fine for a while until I got these errors:

.
.
.

```
Setting up install-info (6.5.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
/usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 3: /etc/environment: aws_access_key_id: not found
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
 installed install-info package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I get java 8 installed?

Answer (score 0):

First, update the apt package index with:

```
$ sudo apt update
```

Once the package index is updated install the default Java OpenJDK package with:

```
$ sudo apt install default-jdk
```

Verify the installation, by running the following command which will print the Java version:

```
$ java -version
```

The output will look something like this:

```
openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.2+9-Ubuntu-3ubuntu118.04.3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.2+9-Ubuntu-3ubuntu118.04.3, mixed mode, sharing)
```

That’s it! At this point, you should have successfully installed Java on your Ubuntu system.

Comment: Thanks. I followed the directions. I am still seeing ichb201@richb201-XPS-13-9370:~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode) when I run the install-default I get: aws_access_key_id: not found
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
 installed install-info package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Please try these commands and post the complete outputs. $ sudo dpkg --configure -a $ sudo apt-get install -f